# Building a search script in PHP

Tags: php, sql, search, autocomplete

I'm trying to build a search script in PHP-SQL something like Facebook or Stackoverflow uses. For example, the user may put in multiple entries; separated by a semi-colon and with Autocomplete on each term. Also: the values are to be stored in SQL; so what type of data should I use or how I should insert those terms in SQL table??

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $().ready(function() {
 $("#job_type").autocomplete("get_job_list.php",
 { width: 224, matchContains: true, selectFirst: false }); });
 </script>
```

PHP code::

```
<?php 
require_once "connection.php";
$q = strtolower($_GET["q"]);
if (!$q) return;
$sql = "select DISTINCT itemid as itemid from eportal where itemid LIKE '%$q%'";
$rsd = mysql_query($sql);
while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($rsd)) {
    $cname = $rs['itemid']; echo "$cname\n"; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: have the user add tags to their post and you and you can search through those or through the titles of their post. I think the `LIKE` SQL keyword would be helpful...

Comment: ı think you need to be more spesific, if your want as like @rcplusplus says ı prefer this way to you. store them in text format with semicolon and then you can use explode for seperate each tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add chosen tags separated into a table with structure `query_id tag_id` (you will also need a table `tags` with a structure `tag_id tag_name`. This way your query will be way easier and faster. Moreover, you will be able to get something like most popular tags easily. SQL is meant for storing data like that. Putting comma separated values is against the basics of SQL.

Comment: I used this concept and coded like this. It worked. Had to fight my way out of the CSS part though, but the back-end code worked. Thanks.
`$q=$_POST['searchword'];
$sql_res = mysql_query("SELECT tag_id, tag_name FROM my_tags WHERE tag_name like '%$q%' ORDER BY tag_id LIMIT 5");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_res))
{
$tagid=$row['tag_id'];
$tagname=$row['tag_name'];
$re_tagname='<b>'.$q.'</b>';
$final_tagname = str_ireplace($q, $re_tagname, $tagname);`